# Operator precedence for sum and division on list in Scala

Tags: scala, list, sum, higher-order-functions, operator-precedence

My example uses `sum` function but this is not the only higher order function I've been having problems with.

**To the point**

It's been a while but I keep catching myself on writing code like:

```
scala> List(2, 5, 7, 11) sum / 3
```

which gives me:

```
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but integer literal found.
```

When I add parentheses:

```
(List(2, 5, 7, 11) sum) / 3
```

I get what I expect though:

```
res3: Int = 8
```

1. So here is my question. Why does the operator precedence work like this? Why doesn't it infer the parentheses?
2. Is there any counter-example that could show that such inferring would lead to a fundamentally wrong results in scala?
3. Why does using `.`change anything. Why does `l.sum / 13` work?

Comment: For one thing, postfix operators (like `sum` in `List(2, 5, 7, 11) sum`) have been hidden behind a flag for a while now. I would consider them to be more or less deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence in Scala is defined by a set of rules. You can find it here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/operators.html

As you can see, alphanumeric letters (such as in `sum`) has the lowest precedence. However, this only applies if you write the function in infix-form (without dots).

Writing the expression like this will solve your problem:

```
List(2, 5, 7, 11).sum / 3
```

Personally, I never call postfix functions without the dot. The Scala compiler even gives you a warning when you write it without the `/ 3` part:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4) sum
<console>:12: warning: postfix operator sum should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scaladoc for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
   List(1,2,3,4) sum
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your third question:

> Why does using `.` change anything. Why does `l.sum / 13` work?

Let's take a more generic piece of code:

```
a b c d
```

How should Scala interpret this? `a.b.c.d`? `a.b(c).d`? `a.b.c(d)`? The fact is that Scala will *always* interpret this as `a.b(c).d` even if it doesn't typecheck correctly. Why does it do that? Because if Scala would decide to interpret `a b c d` differently based on the context of the program, it would be *very* difficult for readers of programs to understand the meaning of the code they are reading.

So if `a.b.c(d)` is what you want, you have to write `a.b c d` so the code can be interpreted unambiguously.